# assertion failure with insertRowsAtIndexPaths

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm facing this error:

`Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:]`

When I'm trying to use `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`

Basically I have a `NSMutableArray` with objects, call this `self.objects`.

I'm adding objects to it like so:

```
MyObject *something = [MyObject new];
[self.objects addObject:something];

NSInteger count = self.objects.count;
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:count];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

A thing to note is that I'm using `section` rather than `row` to achieve cell spacing.

**Update**

Error message:

`*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3512.30.14/UITableView.m:1704`

data source methods:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [self.objects count];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code Which will work:**

> MyObject *something = [MyObject new];
>
> [self.objects addObject:something];
>
> NSInteger count = self.objects.count;
>
> [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:count-1]
>   withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

**Description:**

In your table view implementation you are using one row for reach section. And you are trying to insert row to the section which in not available(created).
So you have to first insert the section that only you can insert rows(in your implementation you are having one row per section so only insert the section).

Comment: I just figured this out too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It will be

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:count-1];
```